# Looping items in a dropdown menu Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm trying to loop categories in a dropdown menu, but clicking on the menu doesn't drop to show each category. But if i test by placing 'link_to' items instead without the loop the dropdown works fine.

```
<div class="ui dropdown item"> 
 <button class="ui primary button">
 Browse By Category  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="menu"> 
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, categories_show_path(category: category.name) %></li>
          <% end %>
              </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: did you inspected and checked whether the html `<li>links</li>` rendered

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan no errors are showing in the web console, and if i placed any other links or items without the loop the dropdown works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake i made, forgot to add "item" div class to properly list down the items.

```
<div class="item"><%= link_to category.name , categories_show_path(category: category.name) %></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check that all the li elements are rendering inside div class="menu", if it is rendering then , you should check that someclass addes on dropdown open , is that class adding to 'menu' div.

you can also write 'li' tag rendering code like below

```
<% Category.pluck(:name).each do |category| %>
  <li><%= link_to category, categories_show_path(category: category) %></li>
<% end %>
```